# Is there a way to set parent folder for Tabulator library?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I installed the download zip version of the Tabulator. I am getting an error "Tabulator is not defined" when I try to set the Tabulator library in previous directory. I have placed the Tabulator library in the previous directory to where the application lives.

I have tried to set the previous directory path in my application.

```
<link href="../tabulator-master/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../tabulator-master/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
```

I am expecting this library to work, but I am getting an error "Tabulator is not defined" when I load the page.

This library works successfully when I place it in the application directory. But I need the library to be in the parent directory as I have other applications to build using this library.

Comment: Could you share the app's tree view?

Comment: `/somelongserverpath/tabulator-master/`
`/somelongserverpath/MyApplicationUsingTabulator/`